# Copiar archivos de una carpeta a otra cambiándoles el nombre en la carpeta destino desde terminal linux

Tags: linux, terminal

Utilizo Manjaro XFCE y estoy copiando unos archivos de un directorio a otro con el siguiente comando:

```
find "/home/$USER/Biblioteca de Calibre/" -iname "*orgullo*prejuicio*austen*.epub" -exec cp {} "/home/$USER/Jane Austen" \;
```

El problema es que me sobrescribe los archivos en la carpeta destino porque algunos se llaman igual ya que son versiones de diferentes traductores, lo ideal sería cambiarles el nombre en la carpeta de destino asignándole un número correlativo, por ejemplo:

El primer archivo que encuentre lo llame así: `Orgullo y prejuicio - Jane austen 01.epub`,
El segundo así: `Orgullo y prejuicio - Jane austen 02.epub`

etc... para evitar que se sobrescriban los archivos que va encontrando.

Answer (score 2):

El comando `cp` tiene [una opción](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) `--backup` diseñada para estas situaciones. Por defecto esta opción añadirá el carácter `~` al nombre del fichero original antes de sobreescribirlo pero [se puede controlar](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm#version-control) (un poco) el nombre del fichero. Para que añada números al final deberías usar la opción `--backup=numbered`. Si quieres usar otro caracter en lugar de `~` se puede controlar con la opción `--sufix`, por ejemplo `--sufix='%'`

Tomando este comando como ejemplo:

```
cp --backup=numbered origfile newfile
```

Si `newfile` ya existe, hará una copia de ese fichero antes de sobreescribirlo. La copia se llamará `newfile.~1~` si no existe un fichero con ese nombre y `newfile.~2~` si ya existe, o el número que toque.